# Error in tsconfig.json in Firebase project for Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I tried to initiate a firebase project but this error appeared in tsconfig.json

> Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
> The file is in the program because:
> Entry point for implicit type library 'node'`

I tried to install types with
`npm install @types/node --save-dev`
but didnt work

I also tried to install previous version of node, because an error said "Invalid version", but didnt resolve the problem

Comment: Are you running `npm install @types/node --save-dev` inside of the functions folder?

Comment: yes, i run and installed types but problem didn't resolve. Should I put something inside of tsconfig.json?

Comment: try adding `"types": ["node"]` under `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json.